# Javascript status from User Agent

Tags: javascript, user-agent

Is it possible to detect if Javascript is enabled/disabled on a browser just by looking at User-Agent.

If yes, what should I be looking for. If no, what is the best way to detect if javascript is enabled/disabled on a user's browser

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a way to detect javascript via the user-agent string. The user agent can be spoofed very easily anyway.

See [antyrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777363/1636917) for how you should be checking for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to detect if JS is disabled by using HTML [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag. It's supported by all known browsers, even old.

```
<noscript>
    this content will be visible only if JS is disabled
</noscript>
```

But User-Agent didn't contain such information. + if JS is disabled how do you want to get User-Agent info? The only possible way is server-side then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When javascript is disabled, you can still do html form posts right? And form posts contain User-Agent information also right?

Comment: @user462455 yes, sure.